# In SQL or mySQL, how can I find a key which has the highest sum in another column while the key appears in two column?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Suppose I have a video chatting app that records the username of two users and the length of the call, the table is data of all the calls.

A person can appear in both user1 and user2. For example, in the table David appears in both user1 and user2. Using the data that we have on the table, how can I write a SQL query that finds the user who has the longest total call length? In this case, David has the longest total call length, which is 50 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEAST/GREATEST` trick here:

```
SELECT user, SUM(length) AS total_length
FROM
(
    SELECT LEAST(User1, User2) AS user, length
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT GREATEST(User1, User2), length
    FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY
    user
ORDER BY
    SUM(length) DESC
```

### Demo

Comment: you don't to add `GREATEST()` in the group by clause since it does not matter whose user is calling to. btw +1

Comment: @JohnWoo Good point, and I would not have thought of doing that.

Comment: Curious about this and made some changes on your demo. `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` will not always work. In this example - http://rextester.com/YAMH47017, I was looking for both `David` and `Mr Tim` to show up in the result (*without limit*) but it didn't.

Comment: @JohnWoo I fixed it...I  guess I posted too fast, though least/greatest is still a viable approach here.  Basically, we need a union because the length of each call is counted _twice_, once for each party in the call.

Answer (score 0):

```
with dat as 
(
Select 'Jhony' User1, 'Jennifer' User2, 23 Call_Length union all
Select 'David','Michael',10 union all
Select 'Lisa','David',40 union all
Select 'Lisa','Jennifer',5
)
Select top 1 sum(a.call_length+nvl(b.call_length,0)),a.user1,b.user2 from 
dat a
left join dat b on a.user1=b.user2
group by a.user1,b.user2
order by  sum(a.call_length+nvl(b.call_length,0)) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I will combine all call time for each users (user1 and user 2) then group by user.  Get the top 1 record based on call time.

```
    Select user, sum(calltime) as calltime
    From
    (Select user1 as user, calltime
     from tbl
      Union all
     Select user2, calltime
     from tbl
     ) t
Group by user
Order by calltime desc
Limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, which *might look dirtier* since mysql doesn't support any window fucntion like any other RDBMS but always give you the exact result including multiple users having the highest total length is by combining the results of both users, calculating its total length and use that value in the outer query comparing to the total sum of the same query without the use of `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT Caller, SUM(length) TotalLength
FROM
    (
        SELECT User1 AS Caller, length FROM calls UNION ALL
        SELECT User2, length FROM calls 
    ) a
GROUP BY Caller
HAVING SUM(length) = (
        SELECT MAX(TotalLength)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT Caller, SUM(length) TotalLength
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT User1 AS Caller, length FROM calls UNION ALL
                    SELECT User2, length FROM calls 
                ) a
            GROUP BY Caller
        ) a
  )
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17d00/1).